# Griefing in the social circles of security experts?

Tags: malware, privacy

When I was in college more than 15 years ago, I had some friends who were taking CS degrees with focus on Information Security.  These folks knew how to write fuzzers, knew how use ring 0 debuggers, and generally had a lot of fun trying to hack each others' personal blogs, e-mails, and desktops because they could. I myself did not focus on this area in college and generally have only passing knowledge of this stuff. However my impression at the time was that within the group of guys who did know how to find exploits and compromise systems, that they did this to each other, and then used the surreptitious access to "grief" each other in weird ways.

Is this common in the IS world? Was this group of engineers unique in their time and place? Do the latest generation of grads do the same thing? Do you think this kind of "teasing" is healthy? Is this just a more advanced example of more simple things, like sneaking into someone's dorm room and changing their wallpaper to goatse?

Is this something that continues well past the school years? My assumption is that people become less juvenile as they get older, everyone goes their separate ways, have kids, etc, but that could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Griefing each other is not nearly as fun as hunting down actual criminals or malicious hackers. Why waste one's time being annoying, when you can use that same time to bring down criminal rings, make discoveries, uncover 0-days, and make a name for yourself? 15 years ago, you had to work hard to discover actual malicious actors to pit yourself against, so attacking your peers was a great way to practice. Now, they come to you. There are also tons of CTF contests, hackable sites/VMs, and bug bounties. There is no end to the amount of practice you can gain without being annoying to others.

The other issue is that now there are hard lines drawn on what is legal, and unauthorized access is illegal. Which is another reason to go for the multitude of practice targets or real ones instead of your friends.

Given the seriousness of the problems in InfoSec today, I don't imagine that people would tolerate this frivolous behaviour from peers.